# Are these 2 monitors same?

Tags: display

I was browsing through a sale and found 2 monitors with same configuration & model number but different pages and a noticeable price difference.

I've ordered one of them , so wanted to consult from experts here are these two models exactly same?

1. [Monitor1](https://www.amazon.in/Acer-Predator-XB271HU-bmiprz-27-inch/dp/B06ZXZ3QBD/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=XB271HU&qid=1565427592&s=gateway&sr=8-1)
2. [Monitor2](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07MRWFTGK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1)

*Thank you*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, according to the specs they are - both are variant B271HU bmiprz.